# change button color flutter

Tags: flutter, button, colors

we have 9 buttons (1 is the lowest the main button and 8 other buttons), and 8 lights (buttons that their color change randonly while pressing the main button). (demonstrated in the picture below).

[image]

how we can change the light color according to the random choice and understand which light turned, save this information and check if the button pressed by the player is the correct one

we tried to used the key factor of the button Widget but it didnt work

```
import 'dart:math';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'Screen building third test.dart';
import 'globals.dart' as globals;

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
    );
  }
}

class LBulb extends StatefulWidget {
  const LBulb({super.key});

  @override
  State<LBulb> createState() => _LBulb();
}

final stopwatchD = Stopwatch();
final stopwatchR = Stopwatch();
bool isChose = false;
int ver = 0;

class _LBulb extends State<LBulb> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    ver = oneOrThree();
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Colors.blue[600]?.withOpacity(0.5),
      ),
      body: Container(
        decoration: const BoxDecoration(
          image: DecorationImage(
              image: AssetImage("assets/images/background2.png"),
              fit: BoxFit.cover),
        ),
        child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            const SizedBox(height: 60),
            const Text(
              "Please click on the appropriate light's button",
              textAlign: TextAlign.center,
              style: TextStyle(
                  color: Colors.black,
                  fontSize: 40,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                  fontFamily: 'Alkatra'),
            ),
            const SizedBox(height: 30),
            Center(
              child: Container(
                height: 500,
                width: 810,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: Colors.white,
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(100),
                  boxShadow: [
                    BoxShadow(
                      color: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.5),
                      offset: const Offset(
                        7.0,
                        7.0,
                      ),
                      blurRadius: 10.0,
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
                child: screenBuilding(
                  distance: 310.0,
                  // Center button
                  centerButton: TextButton(
                    onPressed: () {},
                    child: Container(
                      height: 20,
                      width: 20,
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          color: Colors.black,
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(500)),
                      child: GestureDetector(
                        // while long tap
                        onTapDown: (details) {
                          // start the detection timer
                          stopwatchD.start();
                          // when the player press the button we want to chose
                          // the game version (1 or 3 lights) and light random light/lights
                          if (ver == 1) {
                          } else {}
                        },
                        // when the player release the button
                        onTapUp: (details) {
                          // save the time of the detection time
                          stopwatchD.stop();
                          globals.detectionTime = stopwatchD.elapsed;
                          globals.detectionTimes[globals.numOfTurn] =
                              globals.detectionTime;
                          // reset the values
                          stopwatchD.reset();
                          globals.detectionTime = const Duration(seconds: 0);
                          globals.numOfTurn++;
                          print(globals.detectionTimes);
                          // start the response timer
                          // this timer will be closed when the player will press
                          // the button of the correct light
                          stopwatchR.start();
                        },
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  // the lights buttons
                  buttonsFirstRow: [
                    TextButton(
                      onPressed: () {
                        // check if it's the correct light
                        // when it's the correct light stop the response time.
                        print("clicked1");
                      },
                      child: Container(
                        height: 20,
                        width: 20,
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            color: Colors.black,
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(500)),
                      ),
                    ),
                    TextButton(
                      onPressed: () {
                        print("clicked2");
                      },
                      child: Container(
                        height: 20,
                        width: 20,
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            color: Colors.black,
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(500)),
                      ),
                    ),
                    TextButton(
                      onPressed: () {
                        print("clicked3");
                      },
                      child: Container(
                        height: 20,
                        width: 20,
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            color: Colors.black,
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(500)),
                      ),
                    ),
                    TextButton(
                      onPressed: () {
                        print("clicked4");
                      },
                      child: Container(
                        height: 20,
                        width: 20,
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            color: Colors.black,
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(500)),
                      ),
                    ),
                    TextButton(
                      onPressed: () {
                        print("clicked5");
                      },
                      child: Container(
                        height: 20,
                        width: 20,
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            color: Colors.black,
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(500)),
                      ),
                    ),
                    TextButton(
                      onPressed: () {
                        print("clicked6");
                      },
                      child: Container(
                        height: 20,
                        width: 20,
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            color: Colors.black,
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(500)),
                      ),
                    ),
                    TextButton(
                      onPressed: () {
                        print("clicked7");
                      },
                      child: Container(
                        height: 20,
                        width: 20,
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            color: Colors.black,
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(500)),
                      ),
                    ),
                    TextButton(
                      onPressed: () {
                        print("clicked8");
                      },
                      child: Container(
                        height: 20,
                        width: 20,
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            color: Colors.black,
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(500)),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                  // the first 4 light
                  buttonsSecondRowHalf1: [
                    TextButton(
                      onPressed: () {
                        print("clicked1");
                      },
                      child: Container(
                        height: 20,
                        width: 20,
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            color: Colors.white,
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(500),
                            border: Border.all(width: 3)),
                      ),
                    ),
                    TextButton(
                      onPressed: () {
                        print("clicked2");
                      },
                      child: Container(
                        height: 20,
                        width: 20,
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            color: Colors.white,
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(500),
                            border: Border.all(width: 3)),
                      ),
                    ),
                    TextButton(
                      onPressed: () {
                        print("clicked3");
                      },
                      child: Container(
                        height: 20,
                        width: 20,
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            color: Colors.white,
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(500),
                            border: Border.all(width: 3)),
                      ),
                    ),
                    TextButton(
                      onPressed: () {
                        print("clicked4");
                      },
                      child: Container(
                        height: 20,
                        width: 20,
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            color: Colors.white,
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(500),
                            border: Border.all(width: 3)),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                  // the other 4 light
                  buttonsSecondRowHalf2: [
                    TextButton(
                      onPressed: () {
                        print("clicked5");
                      },
                      child: Container(
                        height: 20,
                        width: 20,
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            color: Colors.white,
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(500),
                            border: Border.all(width: 3)),
                      ),
                    ),
                    TextButton(
                      onPressed: () {
                        print("clicked6");
                      },
                      child: Container(
                        height: 20,
                        width: 20,
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            color: Colors.white,
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(500),
                            border: Border.all(width: 3)),
                      ),
                    ),
                    TextButton(
                      onPressed: () {
                        print("clicked7");
                      },
                      child: Container(
                        height: 20,
                        width: 20,
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            color: Colors.white,
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(500),
                            border: Border.all(width: 3)),
                      ),
                    ),
                    TextButton(
                      onPressed: () {
                        print("clicked8");
                      },
                      child: Container(
                        height: 20,
                        width: 20,
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            color: Colors.white,
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(500),
                            border: Border.all(width: 3)),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Color turnLight(bool isChose) {
    if (isChose == true) {
      return Colors.green;
    }
    return Colors.white;
  }

  int oneOrThree() {
    final rand = Random();
    List<int> a = [1, 3];
    return a[rand.nextInt(a.length)];
  }

  List<int> randomLights(int ver) {
    final rand = Random();
    List<int> a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8];
    List<int> ans = [];
    if (ver == 1) {
      ans[0] = a[rand.nextInt(a.length)];
    } else {
      ans[0] = a[rand.nextInt(a.length)];
      a.remove(ans[0]);
      ans[1] = a[rand.nextInt(a.length)];
      a.remove(ans[1]);
      ans[2] = a[rand.nextInt(a.length)];
    }
    return ans;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To change the light colour according to a random choice and check if the player pressed the correct button Follow the following steps:

1: Define a list of colors for the lights and a variable to store the index of the correct light:

```
List<Color> lightColors = [
  Colors.red,
  Colors.blue,
  Colors.green,
  Colors.purple,
  Colors.white,
  Colors.black,
  Colors.gray,
  Colors.deepPink, // Add More colors as you want 

];

// Here store the correct Light Index


int correctLightIndex = Random().nextInt(lightColors.length);
```

Step 2: Create a list of buttons for the lights using the ElevatedButton widget. Assign the corresponding color to each button from the lightColors list:

```
List<ElevatedButton> lightButtons = List.generate(lightColors.length, (index) {
  return ElevatedButton(
    style: ButtonStyle(
      backgroundColor: MaterialStateProperty.all(lightColors[index]),
    ),
    onPressed: () {
      // Check if the pressed button is the correct one
      if (index == correctLightIndex) {
        // Correct button pressed
        // Handle the logic for a correct guess
      } else {
        // Incorrect button pressed
        // Handle the logic for an incorrect guess
      }
    },
  );
})
```

In the Above Code we have two conditions if user Press a key that have the same light index the show a message to user.

to shuffle the colors array on the main. button press use this logic

```
List<Color> shuffledLightColors = [];
onPressed: () {
  setState(() {
    shuffledLightColors = List.from(lightColors)..shuffle();
  });
},
```

Hope this will help you.